# Link from community welcome email doesn't open change password page

Tags: community, email, change-password

The problem is rather straightforward.
When user registers into our community, he gets a welcome email with a 'get started' link. It's a standard sf behaviour. But for some reason when clicking on this link it logs user immediately into community and shows home page instead of opening change password page and forcing user to set up initial password.

Currently our community has been deployed into 3 test sandboxes. On two of them welcome link works as expected, i.e. opening change password page. But on the third test sandbox we observe this strange behaviour.

To give a bit more info:

- community is published, i.e. active
- password policy in community's profile set as (same for all 3 envs):

> ```
> User passwords expire in  90 days
> Enforce password history  3 passwords remembered
> Minimum password length   8 characters
> Password complexity requirement   Must mix alpha and numeric characters
> Password question requirement Cannot contain password
> Maximum invalid login attempts    10
> Lockout effective period  15 minutes
> Obscure secret answer for password resets Not Checked
> Require a minimum 1 day password lifetime Not Checked
> ```

There should be some configuration difference or whatever.
We've been comparing orgs so far without any success.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I faced the same issue with one of my orgs . Could not get the solution. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally we've figured it out.

For some reason in Administration Permission section of user community's profile 'Password Never Expires' checkbox was set and it forced the system to ignore password policy section of the profile.

Unticking the checkbox has made change password dialog appears again.